# Two third party JavaScript library naming collision

Tags: javascript, collision

I have a page that grabs these two files dynamically.

1. http://cdn.dev.skype.com/uri/skype-analytics.js
2. http://nexus.ensighten.com/somethingelse.js (tracking tool)

Now Skype has following line:

```
s.trackAction(_t, this);
```

Unfortunately the tracking tool JavaScript file also has ***s*** as an objects and due to which `s.trackAction` is not valid for Skype and breaks the whole page.

Comment: Do either of these scripts have a compatibility mode?

Comment: You can use namespacing. Make a global variable and assign the libraries when they are loaded.

Comment: @JustinWood I don't think so.

Comment: @A1rPun That sounds like a great idea. Do you happen to have any example, if not no worries I can look around.

Comment: @jfriend00 has already posted a great solution for you :)

Comment: You could retrieve the JS files via XHR and `eval` them in a closure.  Check out http://blog.rakeshpai.me/2008/10/understanding-eval-scope-spoiler-its.html for a discussion on the scope of `eval` in a closure.

Comment: FYI, http://nexus.ensighten.com/somethingelse.js is not showing any JS code - don't know if that was meant to just be a placeholder URL or have the actual real code.  I looked at the Skype code and it's pretty horrible these days that it would assume that it owns a symbol like `s` with no design for a way around that.   It is not hard to make this interoperable with other code.

Comment: @jfriend00 somethingelse.js file just dummy file as I didn't wanted to post client specific file, it basically has ton of tracking code. I do agree with you! They should have followed some better conventions when minifying the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. Load one script.
2. Save a reference to `s` to a variable, let's say `first_s`.
3. Load the second script
4. Save the a reference to `s` to a variable, let's say `second_s`.

Then, set `s` to whichever of these that you want to be the default global value (e.g. for other people's code).

Then, for your own code or any other code you are using, put it inside this type of block:

```
(function(s) {
    // any code in here that refers to `s` will see the value of second_s
})(second_s);
```

or

```
(function(s) {
    // any code in here that refers to `s` will see the value of first_s
})(first_s);
```

---

Another option I can think of is to modify the Skype code to use a global variable named `skype` instead of `s` and include that modified version in your page.

If the skype code was written properly, it would have an ability to NOT use a simple globally defined name like `s`.  jQuery and others who use the `$` symbol have shown everyone how to do this properly.

Comment: Thank you for quick response jfriend00. 

I am not sure how to follow your direction. 

Both of those files are loaded dynamically and I don't have control over that part. Also, there is no custom code regarding the colliding variable. 

Since you have access to Skype js file, could you possibly show me how to reference variable s of skype file to first_s?

Comment: I am afraid the second option might not work as Skype-analytics.js file is loaded dynamically by skype-uri.js and is placed in a folder called uri, is there anyway to override that by placing a local version?

Comment: @PremShrestha - `skype-uri.ps` is coded to load `skype-analytics.js` from the Skype CDN.  So, without editing a local copy of `skype-uri.ps` to change that, it won't load a modified `skype-analytics.js`.

Comment: I could do that, however do you think I might be violating some rules by doing so?

Comment: @PremShrestha - I don't know what Skype's rules are - you would have to research and decide.  Their code is being a poor interoperable citizen and you're trying to fix it.  You could also ping the Skype dev support and see how they suggest you fix it.  Your other option is to get the client to stop using a global `s` variable in their client JS file.  That's a bad idea for them to be doing that too.

Comment: Just contacted them! Thanks for all your help, really appreciate it.